# What should I do to add the text to the right place in the bar chart?

Tags: r, bar-chart

[image]In a basic bar plot, I want to add text in a right place but my text overlap with the standard error bar. Here are my code and output. Thank you.

```
d<-data.frame(Proband=c(1400,1500), 
          Sibling=c( 1700,1800), 
          Proband2=c( 1200, 1250), 
          Sibling2=c(  1300,  1500))

d <- do.call(rbind, d)
colnames(d) <- c("A","B")


Se<-data.frame(Proband=c(   100,450    ), 
               Sibling=c(    170, 180 ), 
               Proband2=c(120,125 ),
               Sibling2=c(130,150 ))

Se <- do.call(rbind, Se)

colnames(Se) <- c("A","B"))


freq<- c(21,26,32,56,45,66,78,88)

mycolors2<-c(paste0("royalblue", c(4:3)), c("steelblue4", "steelblue3"))

barCenters<-barplot(d, beside = TRUE, ylim=c(0,5000), legend.text = rownames(d), 
                    args.legend = list(x = "topleft", bty="n"), 
                    col=mycolors2, xlab="[![enter image description here][1]][1]Size (kb)",
                    ylab="Average ")


arrows(barCenters, d - Se * 2, barCenters,
       d + Se * 2, lwd = 1.5, angle = 90,
       code = 3, length = 0.05)


text(barCenters, d +  Se * 2 , freq ,cex=1,srt = 90)
```

Comment: use `text(..., adj = -0.5)`

Answer (score 1):

The `y` value you are setting in `text()` is very small, compared to the range displayed on the axis.  Just increase the multiplier on `Se` and the labels will appear above the error bars.

```r
text(barCenters, d +  Se * 5 , freq ,cex=1,srt = 90)
```

[image]

Note: You may want to adjust the spacing formula for your labels, because it currently depends on the magnitude of your standard errors.  This means that bars with large errors will place labels higher on the plot.

Comment: it would be better to add instead of multiply `+ diff(par('usr')[3:4]) / 20`

Answer (score 1):

Since `y=d + Se*2` are the height of your upper error bars, you may want to add a small extension to it. E.g. adding `+ 300` to `x` looks nice. You also could add argument `adj=-.5` to that.

```
text(barCenters, d + Se*2 + 300, freq, cex=1, srt=90)
```

[image]

However, probably the numbers are somewhat misleading at this position and could be confused with just these errors. I suggest to place the number of cases (?) directly into the bars.

```
text(barCenters, 350, freq, cex=.9, col="white")
```

[image]

You might also want to consider explaining the numbers in the description or `?legend`.